# AVPlayer: How come iPhone videos don't get distorted when aspect size varies for video and device?

Tags: ios, iphone, video, avfoundation, avplayer

For instance assume you capture a video at 360x480 resolution using AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium and render it with AVPlayerLayer with videoGravity of AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill. The video renders full screen, without distortion, on 5S devices.

5S devices have a resolution of 320x568, so shouldn't a 360x480 video get stretched vertically or shrunk horizontally?

How does the scaling work so that the aspect size is preserved even though the aspect size of the video differs from the aspect size of the device?

New to AVFoundation and video, so help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Set your `videoGravity` to `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect`.It preserved the aspect size by stretched vertically or shrunk horizontally